# How to change the size input boxes?

Tags: html, input, textbox, styling

I've got the following input boxes in my website but I don't know how to change their width and height. Ben searching but can't find anything, seems strange though if you can't.
Any other styling code or a link to akk the properties are greatly appreciated!

***HTML***

```
<input type="text" id="FontTextBox">
<input type="number" id="FontSizeBox">
<select id="FontStyle">
    <option value="1">Arial</option>
    <option value="2">Comic Sans MS</option>
    <option value="3">Courier New</option>
    <option value="4">Georgia</option>
    <option value="5">Impact</option>                       
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use CSS style - width and height:

```
<input type="text" id="FontTextBox" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
<input type="number" id="FontSizeBox" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
<select id="FontStyle" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <option value="1">Arial</option>
    <option value="2">Comic Sans MS</option>
    <option value="3">Courier New</option>
    <option value="4">Georgia</option>
    <option value="5">Impact</option>                       
</select>
```